# Cannot read web.config file Asp.net core web application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am trying to run some sample code for [ASP.NET Core and Angular 2](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/aspnet-core-and-angular-2).

I cloned the project from https://github.com/PacktPublishing/ASPdotNET-Core-and-Angular-2 and changed the sdk version in the global.json to the current version I have installed (1.0.0-preview2-1-003177). When I run the web application I get the following error page:

[image]

I grepped the project looking for the config file path but came up with nothing. I also contacted support but they aren't helpful.

Does anybody know how to change the config file path?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must open hidden **.vs** folder in root of your solution folder, then find **applicationhost.config** file in the **config** folder.
... and change

```
<virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="......"
```

to the proper path.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be an issue when two people collaborating on a project inadvertently check all files into source control, including applicationhost.config. I'm learning things the hard way with .NET Core.

Comment: @RobReagan this has been a thing since early asp.net. Don't check in your vs folder in source control at all.